# click event on facebook multiple like button

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have multiple like button on same page for different adds. When user click the any like button i has to give him reward. I am using following code for the click event But its work only one time on page.

```
<script>
            FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
          alert('You just liked '+href);
        });

      </script>
```

Is there any way to capture multiple like button on same page?
like button code : `<fb:like href="mysitename.com/adds/ads-id"; layout="button_count" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like><br />`

Comment: Can you post HTML content of buttons ?

Comment: <fb:like href="http://www.mysitename.com/adds/ads-id" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like><br />